# search by php in database in two table

Tags: php, forms

I have a Drop list the user is select from it then the values is Post it too PHP page to search in my database to match 
the problem i have two table the first table i want to select my return from it and my second table i wanna to check the returned value from the drop list to my columns values

```
<form action="firstpagecom.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="jobtype11" name="jobtype122"/>
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="jobsection11" name="jobsection122"/>
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="Experience11" name="Experience122"/>
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="Skills11" name="Skills122"/>
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="Nationalilty11" name="Nationalilty122"/>
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  id="Age11" name="Age122"/>


<div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
<button class="btn btn-action" type="submit" onclick="choose()">Search</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<hr>
</form>
```

and my PHP Page is

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "jobs";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $jobtype = $_POST["jobtype122"];
    $jobsection = $_POST["jobsection122"];
    $Experience = $_POST["Experience122"];
    $Skills = $_POST["Skills122"];
    $Nationalilty = $_POST["Nationalilty122"];  
    $Age = $_POST["Age122"];

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, email FROM employee WHERE employeecv.JobTitle LIKE '%.$jobtype.%' ;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<hr><div class='w3-container'><span class='btn-clipboard'></span><h3><strong style='color:gray'>Employee name :</strong>" . $row['firstname'] ." ". $row['lastname'] .
            "</h3><p><strong style='color:gray'>Employee Phone :</strong>" . $row['phone'] ." </p><p><strong style='color:gray'>Employee Email :</strong>" . $row['email'] .
            "</p><button type='button' class='w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Select </button>   <button type='button' class='w3-btn w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom'><i class='fa fa-comment'></i> Send Massege</button></div>"; 
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "No Employees Available For Now";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two tables you can use joins. for example :

```
$sql = "select * from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id == tbl2.foreing_key where name LIKE '%$search_string%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, email FROM employee WHERE employee.JobTitle LIKE '%.$jobtype.%' ";
```